# What's the difference between screen coordinates and device coordinates?

Tags: c++, mfc, coordinates, cursor-position

I've come across this code:

```
//handler for context menu element; to move an element



void CRTS_SketcherView::OnElementMove()      
{     
      CClientDC aDC(this);
OnPrepareDC(&aDC);                      //Set up the device context
GetCursorPos(&m_CursorPos);             //Get cursor position in screen coords
ScreenToClient(&m_CursorPos);            //convert to client coords
aDC.DPtoLP(&m_CursorPos);           //Convert to logical

      // ...code to initialize the moving of a shape on screen


}
```

i know that screen coordinates of the cursor is it's position on screen, and client coordinates are the coordinates in the client area of the window regardless of the position of the window.
      But then what are device coordinates? The only thing i know is that they're in pixels- but how're they connected to logical(client) and screen coordinates?

Answer (score -1):

Screen co-ordinates are device co-ordinates, they're just two different ways of describing the same thing - the physical device you're drawing into.

GDI can be used for things like printer output, but using the term "screen coordinates" for this is a little confusing. Technically you should use the 'device' moniker for the screen as well, but as its such a common device to use, people (and the docs) give it its own name.

The way to think of all this is to realise there are 2 co-ordinate systems, one that is fixed (device system) and one that is relative (client system).

Comment: the remarks also say that we're first converting the coordinates from screen to client , and then from client coordinates to logical . But aren't logical coordinates and client coordinates the same?